# How do I lift-and-shift my Ubuntu VM to LXD?

Tags: lxd

The blurb from Canonical for the latest release of Ubuntu 16.10 says "the ability to lift-and-shift 80% of Linux VMs to machine containers.” And the LXD site says "LXD is designed to “lift and shift” Linux VMs to containers without modifying the app or operations."

Can anyone point me to some information on how this might be done. I've searched but haven't found anything that might help me lift-and-shift my VMs.

...Andrew

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Here's what I've found... - ["ask ubuntu" question: how to migrate physical 12.04 machine into lxc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680608/how-to-migrate-physical-12-04-machine-into-lxc) - [deimos.fr script: lxc convert hostvm to container](https://blog.deimos.fr/2013/09/11/lxc-how-to-convert-a-hostvm-to-a-container/). - [(somewhat related...) booting a vm in an lxc container](https://stgraber.org/2012/03/04/booting-an-ubuntu-12-04-virtual-machine-in-an-lxc-container/) _Note: I don't have enough reputation to post this as a "comment"._